# Resizable image resource with embedded cap insets

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, png

This is by far not a showstopper problem just something I've been curious about for some time.

There is this well-known `-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:]` API for creating resizable images, which comes really handy when texturing variable size buttons and frames, especially on the retina iPad and especially if you have lots of those and you want to avoid bloating the app bundle with image resources.

The cap insets are typically constant for a given image, no matter what size we want to stretch it to. We can also put that this way: the cap insets are *characteristic* for a given image. So here is the thing: if they logically belong to the image, why don't we store them *together with the image* (as some kind of metadata), instead of having to specify them everywhere where we got to create a new instance?

In the daily practice, this could have serious benefits, mainly by means of eliminating the possibility of human error in the process. If the designer who creates the images could embed the appropriate cap values upon exporting in the image file itself then the developers would no longer have to write magic numbers in the code and maintain them updated each time the image changes. The resizableImage API could read and apply the caps automatically. Heck, even a category on `UIImage` would make do.

Thus my question is: is there any **reliable** way of **embedding** metadata in images?

I'd like to emphasize these two words:

- **reliable**: I have already seen some entries on the optional PNG chunks but I'm afraid those are wiped out of existence once the iOS PNG optimizer kicks in. Or is there a way to prevent that? (along with letting the optimizer do its job)
- **embedding**: I have thought of including the metadata in the filename similarly to what Apple does, i.e. "@2x", "~ipad" etc. but having kilometer-long names like "image-20.0-20.0-40.0-20.0@2x.png" just doesn't seem to be the right way.

Can anyone come up with smart solution to this?

Comment: I still haven't found a solution for embedding the cap inset values in the image metadata but I decided to share what I finally came up with and consider a good compromise: https://github.com/lkxf/uiimage-autocaps

Answer (score 0):

Android has a filetype called nine-patch that is basically the pieces of the image and metadata to construct it. Perhaps a class could be made to replicate it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

Comment: I've taken a look but it seems to me that this is quite an intrusive way of storing the metadata (i.e. in the actual pixels). While I accept that this could work in practice, it would add a significant overhead as the "metadata border" needs to be cropped off the image. But thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: I'm not a fan of Android anyway so happy to hear its inefficient :p